# Weird behavior with viewpager and back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have Fragment1 that has a viewpager loading Fragment2(arg1) and Fragment 2(arg2).

If I click on an listview item in Fragment 2, fragmenttransaction replaces fragment 2 with fragment 3:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft = ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, Fragment3.newInstance());
ft.commit();
```

Here is my debug trace when I hit back on Fragment 3, notice how Fragment2 callbacks arent invoked, which is why it doesnt show up:

```
Fragment3 onDetach
Fragment1 onCreateView
Fragment1 onActivityCreated
```

Same behavior without the viewpager, this works as expected:

```
Fragment3 onDetach
Fragment2 onCreateView
Fragment2 onActivityCreated
```

Comment: What is `R.id.content_frame` the id of?

Comment: the framelayout in my main activity

Comment: So when you click on a list item from either instance of Fragment2, Fragment3 replaces Fragment1. And when you press the back button, nothing happens?

Comment: please see explanation above

Comment: This looks right to me.  You replace Fragment1 with Fragment3, and add the transaction to the backstack.  When you press "back", it replaces Fragment3 with Fragment1 which contains your ViewPager.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue. I missed the part about Fragment2 not being invoked.  So, the way this works is Fragment2 is already in the FragmentManager.  They don't get removed and re-added in the replace.  This is especially true if they are in Fragment1's ChildFragmentManager.  You may need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on your PagerAdapter to have it reload.

Comment: I always just use FragmentManager, not ChildFragmentManager.  Can you show code for your notifyDataSetChanged comment?  The only times I manipulate a list is within my adapter.  notifyDataSetChanged() is called on an adapter when the underlying list changes.  Here my list manipulation occurs within the custom pager adapter class.